# Magento2 - Messed up file permissions. Any way to reset?

Tags: magento2

I accidentally run some magento's command as root user and some directories and files have messed up permissions.

Is there any way to reset the permissions because currently I'm getting errors such as:

> UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file
>   "/var/www/shop//var/log/system.log" could not be opened: failed to
>   open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/shop/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:108
>   Stack trace: #0

Comment: What webserver you using?  Do you have a magento2 specific user? What user does the web server run as?

Comment: Web server runs as user web (unprivileged user), and group www-data. Running on nginx.

Comment: You need a megento2 user, that needs to be able to write to the magento2 installation directory, this is also who will run the cron jobs.

Comment: I do ... the user is `web`. It's also a member of `www-data`. That is my magento user (`web`). I could probably name the user more aptly.

Comment: OK, try what I wrote,

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the following premises.

1. Web server is runing with user:group `www-data:web-data`.
2. Web server is running with umask 0002.
3. Magento2 user:group is `web:web`.
4. `web` user is also a member of `www-data` group.
5. Magento2 installation directory is `/var/www/shop`.

Do these following changes, either as `root` or prefixed with `sudo`.

```
## We're setting a readable baseline, for all directories.  
chown web:www-data -R /var/www/shop
find /var/www/shop -type d -exec chown 2755 {} +

# These directories must be writable by both users. 
find ./var ./generated ./vendor ./pub/static ./pub/media ./app/etc -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
find ./var ./generated ./vendor ./pub/static ./pub/media ./app/etc -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
```

Comment: I know this has been over a year but I found this answer while googling after I messed up my permissions on the server